# scatter like gsctater Matlab

Tags: matlab

How to use `scatter` with markers and colors as `gscatter`, Is it the only way using gscatter?

```
GSCATTER(X,Y,G,CLR,SYM,SIZ) specifies the colors, markers, and size to use.
```

If this is not possible, How could you write scatter to seem similar to gscatter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different markings and colors in `scatter` too. For a simple syntax, you can do the following:

```
scatter(x,y,'bo')%# blue color, 'o' as markings
scatter(x,y,'rx')%# red color, 'x' as markings
```

similarly, substitute `b,r,g,k,w,y,c,m` for blue, red, green, black, white, yellow, cyan and magenta colors and `o,x,*,.,d` for circles, crosses, stars, dots and diamonds as markings.

You can also use the longer form as `scatter(x,y,'property1','value1','property2'...)` to define the colors, markings, marking sizes, etc.

To plot multiple groups using `scatter`, you can use `hold on` and plot different scatter plots on top of each other.